# Share variable between subroutines without global variable names collisions, declaration out-of-subroutine, or passing parameters

Tags: perl

How could I share a variable declared in one subroutine to another subroutine, that's called inside it, without *having global variable names collisions*, or declaring the variable outside the mother caller subroutine, or using any subroutine parameters?

*in other words:* *How could I call a variable defined in a subroutine from a sub-called subroutine?*

---

**More explanation:** *(in case the previous single-line question wasn't descriptive enough)*

Please note that you don't need to read to the end to understand my question. Stop reading if you've got what I'm asking about to save your time.

Let's say I have `subroutine1` and `subroutine2` as so:

```
subroutine1 ();

sub subroutine1 {
  my $word1='hello';
  subroutine2();
}

sub subroutine2 {
  print $word1; #Prints nothing as subroutine2 is unable to access $word1 declared in subroutine1
}
```

My question, specifically, asks about how could I share a variable (`$word1`) declared in one subroutine (`subroutine1`) to another subroutine (`subroutine2`), that's called inside it (`subroutine2` is called inside `subroutine1`), ...

- without having global variable names collision — *Which will let me freely name my variables simple names.*
- without declaring the variable outside the mother caller subroutine (`subroutine1`)
- without using any subroutine parameters

**For example** we could simply achieved it using one of these three simple well-known ways:

*Way 1:* declare `$word1` as global.

```
subroutine1 ();
sub subroutine1 {
  $word1='hello'; #$word1 is declared as global
  subroutine2();
}
sub subroutine2 {
  print $word1;
}
```

*Way 2:* declare `$word1` outside the mother caller subroutine `subroutine1` and limit the scope of it.

```
{
  my $word1='hello';
  subroutine1 ();
  sub subroutine1 {
    subroutine2();
  }
  sub subroutine2 {
    print $word1;
  }
}
```

*Way 3:* pass `$word1` as a parameter to `subroutine2`.

```
subroutine1 ();

sub subroutine1 {
  my $word1='hello';
  subroutine2($word1);
}
sub subroutine2 {
  my $x = shift;
  print $x;
}
```

This example is really trivial and can be solved by any simple way including the three above. But building it simple this way and putting those limits in mind (*no global variable names collisions*, *no out-of-subroutine declaration*, *no parameters usage*) will definitely solve my real complicated problem that I couldn't simplify here for now.

Comment: Impossible by definition. If it's visible by two subs, then it must exist outside of the subs. As such, it must be global, or a declaration outside of the subs must limits its visibility.

Comment: I believe it may be possible somehow. Because while `subroutine2` is being called, `$word1` is still hold on memory. I think there may be somehow something like $currentMotherSubroutineCalledSession::word1 to access the value of `$1word1` at the current call of `subroutine1`.

Comment: `$package::var` is a global var.

Comment: May be targeted global variable? I want to target the scope of the current running session of `subroutine1` in order to access `$word1`

Comment: This is an XY problem. Explain your real issue, not your attempted solution.

Comment: Yeah, you gave us a solution (which you've already ruled out), not a problem.

Comment: I've already solved my real issue using another way. This isn't a question about a specific issue to solve. It's a questions about "How could I use perl this way …" .

Comment: No, it's not. What you've asked is impossible by definition, regardless of language.

Comment: @ikegami I know how to do it, but I'm not going to say how because someone's going to put it in production.

Comment: @melpomene, You mean PW? Using PW basically makes lexical variables global (by navigating Perl's internal structure of a sub). So technically, what I said is still correct. And like you said, it's not something any program should do.

Comment: @melpomene, Speaking of bad advice: [This](http://pastebin.com/ejV6Dvw2). In fact, that the same approach as in my answer (store the value in localized global var, namely `&subroutine2`), but way worse! (Imagine if someone did `\&subroutine2` when it was localized?)

Comment: @ikegami I'm asking about a feature that would be powerful if it exists in Perl. What I understand is that when you call `subroutine1` and declare `$word1` within its scope, `$word1` will still be declared till the interpreter reaches the closing brace of `subroutine1`. When we call `subroutine2` from within `subroutine1`, and haven't reached the closing brace of `subroutine1` yet, we will still have `$word1` declared. We can target main scope by using $main::varName. My question is "Is there a something similar for targeting currently running subroutines scopes?"

Comment: You've asked for a 4-wheeled car without wheels. It's impossible by definition.

Comment: Re "*We can target main scope by using $main::varName.*", Yes, and that's why it's a global variable. Re "*Is there a something similar for targeting currently running subroutines scopes?*", That would similarly make the variable a global variable. **You don't seem to know what "global variable" means!** It means the variable is visible (accessible) from any code. You're asking how to make a global variable without using global variables, and that's impossible!

Comment: @ikegami Great! Then I will change my description to be: Could we make the variable 'global' (visible from any code) but not to collision with any similarly named global variable in the main scope?

Comment: Re "*"Is there a something similar for targeting currently running subroutines scopes?*", Yes, It's called dynamically-scoped variables. While the var is global, the value is only visible to calls subs. I've already shown you how to do that. (That said, it's a very bad idea.)

Comment: @ikegami sorry for misusing the word `global`.

Comment: Feel free to give them unique names.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135535/discussion-between-omar-and-ikegami).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the two subroutines aren't nested, then your request is impossible by definition. If it's visible by two non-nested subs, then it must exist outside of the subs. As such, it must be global, or a declaration outside of the subs must limit its visibility to some lexical scope that includes both subs.

So that leaves nested subs.

```
sub tree_visitor {
   my @rv;

   local *_helper = sub {
       my ($node) = @_;
       push @rv, $node->text;
       for my $child ($node->children) {
          _helper($child);
       }
   };

   _helper($node);
   return @rv;
}
```

Something closer to what you want is called a "dynamic-scoped variable". It uses a global variable, but the value of the variable is restored after the calling sub exits.

```
sub subroutine2 {
   our $x;
   print $x;
}

sub subroutine1 {
   local our $x = 'hello';
   subroutine2();
}

subroutine1();
```

It would be must easier to help you if we knew what problem you are actually facing. But it's either going to involve a global var or a closure.